# excel to create a new sheet for each row

Tags: vba, excel

**The Data**

Sheet one will be for data entry. Each row will represent a Service Ticket. Each column will represent data about the service incident such as serial number or model number.

**Desired Result**

For each row containing data in a particular field (Column A ~ "Ticket Number) Excel will create a new sheet (The service ticket) based on a template and place the data from the corresponding row into the designated cells.

*Thank you in advance for any assistance you may be able to provide.*

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying that you should be careful with this as there is a limit to the number of sheets in a workbook. But here is some code in vb.  It should give you the logic to get it done in vba.  There will just be some difference in referring to the sheet and maybe cells.

You will need to declare the worksheet that you are reading through

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ea.Worksheets(1)
```

It may start at sheet index 0 so Set ws = ea.Worksheets(0)
Or there is something like Excel.Application.Activsheet

Here is the logic to loop through the rows and check the value of column A.

```
dim lRow as integer
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value <> "" Then Then
        'If cell A is not blank we then call the worksheet add function.
        'Pass the name you want the worksheet and the page setup arguments.
        WorksheetAdd ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value, xlPaperLetter, xlPortrait
        ws.name = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
    End If

    lRow = lRow + 1
    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate

Loop
```

You will want a worksheetAdd function like this

```
Private Sub WorksheetAdd(szJobNumber As String, Papersize As XlPaperSize,     PageOrientation As XlPageOrientation)
Dim bDisplayAlerts As Boolean

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    'Add worksheet to workbook.
    Set ws = ea.Worksheets.Add
    ws.Name = szJobNumber
    With ws.PageSetup
        .Orientation = PageOrientation
        .LeftFooter = "&D"
        .CenterFooter = "&A"
        .RightFooter = "Page &P of &N"
        .Papersize = Papersize
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
    If Err.Number = 1004 Then
        If MsgBox("There has been an error(#1004). Contact support. Excel is not installed or produced an error. Also, check for default printer.",vbCritical,     "Information") = vbOK Then
            'Unload frmPTReports
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This is beyond my expertise.